# Is it possible to get type from an array of object based on specific condition?

Tags: typescript

I want to get the types of a specific element from an array of objects `as const` based on some given conditions. But I don't know how to do it.

Example -

```
const EXAMPLE = [
  {
    type: 'tab',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    type: 'tab',
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 3,
  },
] as const;
```

Here is what I can do

```
type TExampleIds = typeof EXAMPLE[number]['id'];
// TEampleIds = 1 | 2 | 3
```

Here is what I want to do - I just want to get the type of `ids` where its `type` is `tab`.

```
type TTabIds = typeof EXAMPLE[number]['id'] where typeof EXAMPLE[number]['type'] === 'tab';
// TTabIds = 1 | 2
```

Question -
Is what I want to achieve possible? and how I can do it if so?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to filter examples with required type:

```
type OfType<T, E = typeof EXAMPLE[number]> = E extends { type: T } ? E : never;

type TTabIds = OfType<'tab'>['id']; // 1 | 2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogDQIIFkAKAZOMC8MDaAsAFAwwDeJZZUAngA4CmAXDAORQCGARmwDRVqASwAmrAIwDSMAL5SylaTQYt2XXvOFiYAJk1zBi6jDpNWbAOYAnEAFd6-QWVGsAzPqkBdGJwgxQkFAA3CQkpowwAPIAZgAqKgA8sXzwuCYqINHwyOhY+GC2ALbcjFaeAHxp2IwAHlCMYCJ+5OlmMLGyMAD8qaxgjABupSHEYSrtsTwAkk1pMfFMCRw8bOX4bKJsnkEwAPS7MOIwAD66QA)